# Regex to check middle 3 characters

Tags: java, regex

I am having an issue where i need to see if the provided string contains middle 3 characters as I am looking for.

For eg. we will always get 9 character string which, in which middle 3 characters I want to compare with say for eg "abc". If condition match then I want to apply some logic. Can anyone give me example for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your case substring sounds more straight forward.

Comment: Is the length of the string fixed?  Does it matter where in the middle the substring is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this is what you want

```
^.{3}abc.{3}$
```

Comment: Is this expession valid for shell script. If i try like this

Comment: if [ "$1" == ^.{3}abc.{3}$ ];
then
 echo "Condition did match !!!"

else
 echo "Condition did not match"
fi

Comment: this above script always says "condition didnot match" even if i pass string as "pppabc001"

Comment: $1 repesent argument passes in this scripts

Comment: @user509755 sorry for late response..i dnt knw abt shell script

Answer (score 2):

`^.*abc.*$`

You could also use something like, `^.{3}abc.{3}$` to match only the middle three characters.

Answer (score 0):

It probably makes more sense to use `substring` and `equals`:

```
if(s.substring(3, 6).equals("abc"))
    // ...
```

But if you really want a regex, you can write:

```
if(Pattern.compile("...abc...", Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(s).matches())
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int mid = (test.length()/2);
string = string.substring(mid-1, mid+2);
if (string.equals("abc"))
{
   do stuff
}
```

Here is an example using substrings to get the middle three characters.  You may want to add a check, just in case the string is less then 3 characters long to prevent errors.  Change abc to whatever you want to check for.